# How to add Ruby script code in BSF postprocessor to skip user registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter, ruby-jmeter, post-processor

While Using Jmeter for Performane testing of a Ruby Application with 100 user, we ran it for user regsitration.To login, tt requires user confirmation via email but while testing on local environment we have a method 'Skip_confirmation' (run in console) in application to skip the user confirmation via url which contains the token.
How i can add the ruby method in Jmeter to skip user confirmation after registration.

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

If by console you mean a shell or command , you can use [OS PROCESS SAMPLER](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

if not, then have a look at code of Skip_confirmation to see what it does and add more info in your question.

A 3rd option is to use [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with JRuby as explained here:

- http://remembermakethingsbetter.blogspot.fr/2012/10/jruby-and-apache-jmeter.html